# Use HtmlHelper in Kendo Template

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-template

What I'm trying to do seems pretty simple but I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

I have a `Kendo Template` and I am wanting to use an `HtmlHelper` that I created inside of it but I'm having an issue with passing the value into it.

This is what my template looks like:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="reviewTemplate">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                #:ProducerProfileDisplay#
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayRating(#:Rating#))
            <p>#:ReviewText#</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The problem with this is it just doesn't like the syntax at all and I can't compile my project. And if I decide to put it inside of quotes then it will literally just pass in the string `#:Rating#`.

By the way, the method I created is expecting a double.

Any ideas?

Comment: You just can't mix C# and Kendo Templates. Pick one: Or you proccess the `Rating` in C# and sets the value to the viewModel before loading the view; Or you create the `DisplayRating` in javascript in order to call it inside the template. I would stay with the first one.

Comment: Templates render html in the client with javascript after the page has loaded whereas C# Razor runs on the server before the page is delivered, hence the two cannot be combined. The choices given by DoneVoteMeDown are exactly right. Which you choose is up to you, but I would be inclined to write a javascript version of your helper which you can can call as a function, that returns html, between a pair of # markers. Only because I prefer to render html in views or in the client rather than include html within the view model.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I went ahead and just made a javascript function that did the same thing as my html helper and it works perfectly. :)